# Passport callback not being called

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-saml

While trying to implement the passport-same authentication methods I have hit a roadblock. The callback function passed to the `passport.authenticated` function does not get called.

```
router.post("/saml/callback",
    function (req, res, next) {
        req.body.SAMLResponse = req.body.SAMLResponse.replace(/[\n\r]/g, "");
        next();
    },
    function (req, res, next) {
        console.log("Calling passport handler");
        console.log(req.body);
        try {
            const response = passport.authenticate("saml",
                {
                    failureRedirect: "/saml/error",
                    failureFlash: true
                }, (error, user, info) => {
                    console.log(error, user, info);
                    next();
                })(req, res, next);
            console.log(response);
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        console.log("Line after passport handler");
    },
    function (req, res) {
        res.redirect("/saml/success");
    }
);
```

My express app hangs when entering this method but only with 1 specific saml provider (using https://samltest.id as test provider DOES work with the exact same code). It seems that an error occurs in this authenticate method but I cannot for the live of me find this error.

How do I get the error in this callback.

Log output:

> Calling passport handler
>   `{SAMLResponse: 'base64encoded saml response'}`
>   undefined
>   Line after passport handler
>   Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ip:443

Comment: Don't you need to pass `error` or `user` to `next()`? See http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/#custom-callback

Comment: @laggingreflex would make no difference since the line above doesn't even get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to not at all be in this piece of code but instead in the initiation of the saml provider.

I have a callback function in `Strategy({cert: function(callback)....});` which tries to fetch the signing certificates for the saml response. The IDP was however not accessible from my SP due to it being a test server, therefor the callback never got called.

TL;DR; If you are using the `cert` key in your `Strategy` definition; and said key utilises a callback, check if that callback gets called!